# error running iReport designed report in JasperReports Server (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I designed a report in *iReport* that has a straight forward query as the main report and a sub report with another simple query.  Neither query has any parameters passed to it, however they both deal with timestamps extensively.

The combined report runs fine within *iReport* and if i remove the sub-query and load both into *JasperReports Server* they will run independently.  However, when I try to run the full report that includes the sub-report, I get the following error and stack trace:

```
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.
Error Message

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Parameter "DATABASE_TIMEZONE" does not exist.
Error Trace

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Parameter "DATABASE_TIMEZONE" does not exist. 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.getValueParameter(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:606) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.getValueParameter(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:621) 
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.getValueParameter(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:150) 
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.<init>(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:134) 
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuterFactory.createQueryExecuter(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuterFactory.java:50) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:728) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:629) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1159) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:802) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:746) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:640) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This is is a [known bug](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport/tracker/view.php?id=5707) as far as I can tell, but isn't receiving much attention.  Has anyone encountered this error and come up with a workaround or at least an explanation of what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that this question has an answer:

My solution was to modify my SQL query to return all my data in one query and remove the sub-report.  This seems like a silly work around for a fairly important feature but it is working in the meantime.